# macOS - Local notification dismissed in few seconds

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-catalina, unusernotificationcenter

I used this [notification guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html) from apple to show local notification. And the notification is appearing on screen. But I see two different behaviours compared to the notifications from Calendar app.

Calendar app notification behaviour:

1. Once notification banner appeared. It says on screen untill we do some action on it.
2. The action buttons (Close, Snooze) are always visible.

My App notification behavior:

1. Once notification showdn it is getting hidden automatically after few seconds.
2. The action buttons are not displayed when notification is on screen. But the buttons are displays when We hover the notification with mouse pointer or cursor.

I used `UserNotifications.framework` with SDK 10.15 and I tested this on Catalina (10.15.6).
I expect the notification to behave, how the Calendar arpp notification works.

Any idea, why it behaves differently. Or is there any property to achieve the Calendar app notification behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The notification is dismissed in 5 seconds since the notification alert style as 'Banner'. The notification stays always on screen until user does any action after changing the Notification alert style settings to 'Alerts' in System Preferences.

[image]